# How to convert 64 bit int to binary presentation?

Tags: c

How to convert 64 bit int to binary presentation (big endian)? For reverse task I use these functions:

```
int readInt (struct str *buf) {
    buf -> cur_len = buf -> cur_len + 4;
    return 
    (((buf -> data[buf -> cur_len - 3 ] & 0xff) << 24) | 
    ((buf -> data[buf -> cur_len - 2 ] & 0xff) << 16) |
    ((buf -> data[buf -> cur_len - 1 ] & 0xff) <<  8) |
    ((buf -> data[buf -> cur_len ] & 0xff) <<  0));
};


long unsigned int 32Bit(struct str *buf) {  // 32
    return ((long unsigned int)readInt(buf)) & 0xffffffffL;
};

long unsigned int 64Bit(struct str *buffer) { //64
    long unsigned int result = 32Bit(buf);
    result *= 4294967296.0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Identifiers cannot start with numerals in C.

Comment: What does the `struct str` definition look like? a 64bit integer is already "in" binary representation. are you referring to converting it to a binary string or getting the information of it into the `str` struct?

Comment: The size of `long` varies between compilers and 32/64-bitness.

Answer (score 3):

Serialising a 64 bit unsigned number into an array of `unsigned char`, storing 8 bits in each in big-endian order, can be done like so:

```
void serialise_64bit(unsigned char dest[8], unsigned long long n)
{
    dest[0] = (n >> 56) & 0xff;
    dest[1] = (n >> 48) & 0xff;
    dest[2] = (n >> 40) & 0xff;
    dest[3] = (n >> 32) & 0xff;
    dest[4] = (n >> 24) & 0xff;
    dest[5] = (n >> 16) & 0xff;
    dest[6] = (n >>  8) & 0xff;
    dest[7] = (n >>  0) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `& 0xff`? Truncation to smaller unsigned types is well-defined, I think you can just omit that. Also, you're assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`. ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I need the `& 0xff` precisely because I am *not* assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8` - I am assuming `CHAR_BIT >= 8`, but then that is required so it is safe.  The `& 0xff` should be eliminated by the optimiser on common systems.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use built-in types for serialization; instead, when you need to know the exact size of a type, you need fixed-width types:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char buf[8]; // 64-bit raw data

uint64_t little_endian_value =
   (uint64_t)buf[0] + ((uint64_t)buf[1] << 8) + ((uint64_t)buf[2] << 16) + ... + ((uint64_t)buf[7] << 56);

uint64_t big_endian_value =
   (uint64_t)buf[7] + ((uint64_t)buf[6] << 8) + ((uint64_t)buf[5] << 16) + ... + ((uint64_t)buf[0] << 56);
```

Similarly for 32-bit values, use `uint32_t` there. Make sure your source buffer uses *unsigned* chars.

Comment: This is untrue: serialization was being done successfully long before the fixed-width types were introduced.  In this case, `unsigned long long` would be a perfectly fine data type to use, because it must be at least 64 bits long, which means that it can happily store the deserialised value (even if it might waste some space if it's a larger type on a given platform).

Comment: @Caf: OK, for deserialization that's fine, but if you want to *serialize* with `fwrite(outfile, (const char*)&x, sizeof(x));` then you better know the size of your type! (Sure, you *can* use primitive types and just write out a fixed number of bytes, but the fixed-width types are more idiomatic when you're dealing with serialized data.)

Comment: @caf: it was done by using the known type sizes for a single platform (non-portable) or using lots of #ifdefs to specify the sizes on multiple platforms.  <stdint.h> just encapsulates all those #ifdefs for you.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: The method using shifts and masks does not require either fixed-size types or `#ifdef` trees: the minimum type sizes are sufficient, because it works on values rather than representation.

Comment: @caf: You're right, everything is written in terms of values and fairly independent of the unsigned type that you use. The one point when *deserializing* that I would make, though is that you need to be able to shift by enough bytes without overflowing, so I think I really do want those casts to a fixed-size type. Your serialization code is fine, it simply puts the responsibility on the user to know whether her values fit into 64 bit or not, but that's sensible.